# Problems defining a variable with node

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to work with a Smart Contract throw node, the piece of code which is giving some problems is this one:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address,"pending").then((tnxCount)=>{
console.log(tnxCount);
var rawTxOptions = {
 nonce: web3.utils.numberToHex(txnCount),
 from: account.address,
 to: null, // public tx
 value: "0x00",
 data: '0x'+contractBin+contractInit, // contract binary appended with initialization value
 gasPrice: "0x0", // Set to 0 in GoQuorum networks
 gasLimit: "0x24A22" // max number of gas units the tx is allowed to use
};

 console.log("Creating transaction...");
 const tx = new Tx(rawTxOptions);
 console.log("Signing transaction...");
 tx.sign(privateKey);
 console.log("Sending transaction...");
 var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
 const txr = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + 
 serializedTx.toString('hex').toString("hex"));
 console.log("tx transactionHash: " + txr.transactionHash);
 console.log("tx contractAddress: " + txr.contractAddress);

});
```

And I am having the following error:

```
 (node:8930) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: txnCount is not defined
    at /home/ubuntu/Escritorio/Raft-project/public_tx2.js:24:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8930) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8930) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The error is in this line nonce: web3.utils.numberToHex(txnCount) but I don't understand why if I have it on the .then, how can I solve this problem?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in one place I have txn and in other one I have tnx